# How to select a list in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to enter an address then they propose me some addresses and I had no idea how to select the first option they give me.

If you want to try, at the second step on this link: https://www.sneakql.com/en-GB/launch/culturekings/womens-air-jordan-1-high-og-court-purple-au/register

```
adresse = chrome.find_element_by_id('address-autocomplete')
            adresse.send_keys(row['Adresse']) #Adress from a file
            time.sleep(5)
            country = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="suggestion_0"]').click();
```

Inspect element:

[image: Inspect element]

Comment: That's not a normal Select option drop down. You need to click on input box and then store all option in a list and then iterate the list and click on your desired element. Paste the HTML in normal text here.

Comment: Please add a code that you are executing

Comment: Next time when posting a question add there full code to reproduce the issue. It will be easier to answer the question and you will get less downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should click this field and wait for the first option to become clickable.

I've wrote some code to test if my solution works and it works in all cases for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://www.sneakql.com/en-GB/launch/culturekings/womens-air-jordan-1-high-og-court-purple-au/register'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'AGREE')]"))).click()  # ACCEPT COOKIES

#  Making inputs of the first page
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#firstName"))).send_keys("test")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#lastName"))).send_keys("Last name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#preferredName"))).send_keys("Mr. President")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email"))).send_keys("mr.president@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#password").send_keys("11111111")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#phone").send_keys("222334413")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#birthdate").send_keys("2000-06-11")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()

# Second page and answer to your main question
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#address-autocomplete"))).send_keys("street")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#suggestion_0"))).click()
```

Please note, that not all explicit waits are required and I used css selectors because I am not sure that all elements ids are correct.

My output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the first option with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="suggestion_0"]')
```

**UPD**
The element you trying to click is out of the view. You have to do the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

suggestion_0 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="suggestion_0"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(suggestion_0).perform()
suggestion_0.click()
```

Comment: Error : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="jss50" role="option" aria-setsize="1" aria-posinset="1" id="suggestion_0">...</li> is not clickable at point (456, 739). Other element would receive the click: <li class="jss50" role="option" aria-setsize="1" aria-posinset="1" id="suggestion_0">...</li>